# How many threads are running in my java program?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running simple program and here is log

```
Total Thread : 6  // using Thread.activeCount()
pool-1-thread-143
```

Here is class

```
public class Test implements Runnable{

    String              ul;
    ExecutorService     threadPool;
    public Test(String s, ExecutorService executor)
    {
        this.ul = s;
        threadPool  =   executor;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Fun(ul);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Fun(String ss) throws IOException
    {

    // .... 
        System.out.println("Total Thread : "+Thread.activeCount());
       Iterator iterator = links.iterator();
       while(iterator.hasNext())
       {
          Element ele = iterator.next();
          String s = ele.getprop("....");
          if(!Model.condition(s))
          {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
              threadPool.execute(new Test(s, threadPool));
          }
       }        
    }
}
```

Here is Main.java

```
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);        
    executor.execute(new Test("this is something", executor));          
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }
```

So how many actual thread is running by my program ?
Have  I implemented `executor.execute()` correct in this program?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I dont see any crawler class in code which you are passing to execute method.

Comment: you can get a thread dump to see all threads - e.g. `jstack {pid}`

Comment: 1+5=6. Main + executor's ones

Answer (score 1):

One thread for the main program and five threads in the pool for a total of 6 as you see. And it's a perfectly good use of a `Threadpool`, although it seems a bit convoluted that the `Test` executes a new `Test`?!

Cheers,

Comment: 1st pool and some sequence number for the thread. It's not that there are 143 current threads, but more like 143 threads have been started over time, and most have terminated

Comment: `threadPool.execute(new Test(s, threadPool));` this way actually i want to run the task using same thread pool

Answer (score 1):

The `Executors` call  creates a fixed size thread pool of 5. The application starts on a `main` thread...thus 5+1 = 6

Comment: from your code `Thread.currentThread().getName()` -> the name of current thread

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of code is a bit clumsy.
This portion looks a bit ugly `threadPool.execute(new Test(s, threadPool));` as you are passing reference of variable as parameter which itself is making call to method.

I would rather keep Thread pool executor outside Test class and pass multiple instance of test class to it.

Count as explained in answers above is 5 + 1 main thread.

This is how i will do it. Main method can be improved further by adding more modularity but aim is ThreadPool should exist outside Runnable implementation.

```
public class Test implements Runnable{

    String              ul;    
    public Test(String s)
    {
        this.ul = s;        
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Fun(ul);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Fun(String ss) throws IOException
    {

    // .... 
        System.out.println("Total Thread : "+Thread.activeCount());

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

       }        
    }
}

public class MyRunnerClass {

   public static void main(String args[]){
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
     String s = "this is something";

      Iterator iterator = links.iterator();
      while(iterator.hasNext())
       {
          Element ele = iterator.next();
          String s = ele.getprop("....");
          if(!Model.condition(s))
          {              
              executor.execute(new Test(s, threadPool));
          }
       } 

   }
}
```

Comment: Your code will do the job but will not be advised as it might make things difficult to debug and extend further.

Comment: can you pls improve it?